# Driver's door does not activate dome light or warning toner for headlights on

Tags: honda

2006 Honda CRV SE: Driver's door does not activate dome light or warning toner for headlights on.  Door switch checks out ok.

Comment: If the dome light actuates when the passenger door opens, then there's a fault in the wiring or a connection, somewhere between the driver's door switch and whatever it connects to.

Comment: How do you know the switch checks out OK, if neither the dome light nor light minder are triggered?